# Using Query Hint on FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, for-xml, query-hints

does anyone know how about using Query Hints with the "FOR XML" statement? My (Sub-)Query looks like this:

```
SELECT ','+RTRIM(username) FROM @TmpDistinctUsers 
WHERE vergabe_nr = b1.vergabe_nr            
ORDER BY  rn DESC
FOR XML path(''),elements
```

When I add

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

I get Syntax errors...

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add that as a part of the subquery.

Have a look at the documentation for [SELECT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

```
[ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]
```

OPTION goes to the end of the main query.